# Condicion de ciclo no se esta cumpliendo Java

Tags: java

estoy teniendo un problema, mi ciclo no se esta cumpliendo, se devuelve a mi switch. Si yo ingreso de 2 en cantidadAsientosTeatro se supone que tiene que entrar 2 veces en el ciclo, pero este se esta saliendo no se porque.

```
    public static char[][] muestraRegistrarReserva(char mat[][]) // Registrar reserva.
{ // Inicio METODO.
    char matriz[][] = mat;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int  filaTeatro, columnaTeatro , acumuladorCantidadAsientosTeatro = 0 , cantidadAsientosTeatro;


    do
    { // Inicio DO.
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de asientos que desea reservar: ");
        cantidadAsientosTeatro = sc.nextInt();
        while(cantidadAsientosTeatro <= 0)
        { // Inicio WHILE.
            System.out.println("INCORRECTO: Por favor, ingrese una cantidad de asientos correcta: ");
            cantidadAsientosTeatro = sc.nextInt();
        } // Fin WHILE.



    acumuladorCantidadAsientosTeatro+=1;        
    } // Fin DO.
    while(cantidadAsientosTeatro != acumuladorCantidadAsientosTeatro);
return matriz;
} // Fin METODO.
```

Comment: En primer lugar, no es que tiene que entrar dos veces al  `do while`, sino que ingresa una vez y tiene que iterar o repetir (el código que está entre llaves) dos veces al ingresar valor 2. Después debes tomar el valor de entrada del Scanner antes de entrar al `do while`, estas lineas: `System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de asientos que desea reservar: ");` `cantidadAsientosTeatro = sc.nextInt();`. Igualmente no sé para que está `matriz` si no la usas. Podrías explicar que es lo que queres hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola mira la sentencia `do` es lo que realizara en cada ciclo. El `while` comprobara tu condición para finalizar o continuar el ciclo. Si tu `while`regresa un valor `false` es cuando termina el ciclo pero mientra siga dando un valor True tu ciclo se seguirá haciendo;

por lo tanto

```
while(cantidadAsientosTeatro <= 0)
```

siempre ingresas un numero mayor a 0 por lo que regresa un valor `false`y nunca se cumple tu condición y no realiza ni un ciclo. Ademas el `Do` no puede terminar despues del `While` deberías ponerlo así

```
 do
        { // Inicio DO.

         System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de asientos que desea reservar: ");
            cantidadAsientosTeatro = sc.nextInt();

        }//Fin Do

            while(cantidadAsientosTeatro <= 0);
            { // Inicio WHILE.
                  System.out.println("INCORRECTO: Por favor, ingrese una cantidad de asientos correcta: ");
                  cantidadAsientosTeatro = sc.nextInt();

            } // Fin WHILE.
```

ahora la verdad no se que es lo que trata de hacer tu código pero para realizar una cantidad de ciclos deseada deberás sacar lo que esta en el `do` afuera

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de asientos que desea reservar: ");
        cantidadAsientosTeatro = sc.nextInt();
```

y luego usar tu variable cantidadAsientosTeatro quitando le 1 hasta que llegue a 0 y con el `while` le daras fin a tu ciclo.

```
     int ciclos=1;
     System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de Ciclos: ");
     int cantidadDeCiclos = sc.nextInt();

     do
        { // Inicio DO.

         System.out.println("Cantidad de Ciclos Realizados° : "+ ciclos);
         ciclos++;
         cantidadDeCiclos--;
        }//Fin Do

         while(cantidadDeCiclos > 0 );
          { // Inicio WHILE.
             System.out.println("FIN DEL CICLO "); 
            } // Fin WHILE.
```